# QGIS SVG custom symbols more than 2 colours

Tags: qgis, svg

I would like to know if it possible to have a SVG symbol with more than 2 colors. I would like to have one with up for colors? A simple point with 4 colors representing different species sighted in a place. I do not which a pie.

Any answer would be helpful

Comment: Do you need the symbols to be dynamic (i.e. do you need them to change depending on the attributes of each point)?

Answer (score 5):

The solution isn't an SVG marker, it's even simpler. Create a compound marker.

Select the quarter circle marker:

[image]

Duplicate three times the marker:

[image]

Set rotation (0º, 90º, 180º, 270º) and color for each quarter:

[image]

Enjoy:

[image]

Also, you can design your own symbols in an SVG editor (like [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/)) and add them in QGIS.